# SQL Query for CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two table one is master table and another table is you can select item from first table.

MasterTable

```
ItemID      ItemName
1           Football
2           Cricket
3           Badminton
```

SelectionTable

```
UserID     SelectedItemId
1            2
1            3
2            1
```

OutPut

```
UserId      SelectedItemID     SelectionStatus
1            1                   False
1            2                   True
1            3                   True
```

Query

```
SELECT  S.UserId,M.ItemID,
        CASE M.ItemID 
            WHEN 1 Then 'True'
            WHEN 2 Then 'True'
            WHen 3 Then 'True' END AS SelectionStatus
From MasterTable M
JOIN SelectionTable S ON S.SelectedItemID=M.ItemID      
WHERE S.UserId=1
```

If no any item selected then all are false.I don't know how to do.

Comment: Switch your m.itemID to S.SelectedItemID.  and LEFT join master to Selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `User` table, you can get the status of every user / item combination by querying cartesean product (cross join).

The status `True` or `False` can be determined the presence or absence of a corresponding record in the `SelectionTable`.

```
select
    u.UserId,
    m.ItemId,
    case
        when exists
            (select *
            from SelectionTable s
            where s.UserId = u.UserId
              and s.SelectedItemId = m.ItemId)
        then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end
from MasterTable m, User u
```

This technique can be applied to the single user case (`UserId` equals 1) as follows:

```
select
    m.ItemId,
    case
        when exists
            (select *
            from SelectionTable s
            where s.UserId = 1
              and s.SelectedItemId = m.ItemId)
        then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end
from MasterTable m
```

Comment: I have only two table, why assume another table?

Comment: Usually when you have a `UserId` it corresponds to an auto-generated value.  I've modified my answer to work for a single `UserId` and only uses the 2 specified tables.

Comment: by the way i use your second technique. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `else` and a `left join` from `SelectionTable` to `MasterTable`.

```
SELECT  S.UserId,M.ItemID,
        CASE M.ItemID 
            WHEN 1 Then 'True'
            WHEN 2 Then 'True'
            WHen 3 Then 'True' 
            else 'False'
            END AS SelectionStatus
From SelectionTable S
  left JOIN MasterTable M ON S.SelectedItemID=M.ItemID      
WHERE S.UserId=1
```